# Integrate android project into React Native

Tags: android, react-native

i am new to react native...... I had a developed android project and now i want to integrate it into React Native. how can i import or migrate or integrate it into React native? any help..........!
i.e, if i run `react-native run-android` in command prompt my old Project have to be run. i have tried to import my entire project as a library even then it was running `app` folder only by default.....  In `Android` folder instead of `app` folder `my_Project` have to be come......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React Native is great when you are starting a new mobile app from scratch. However, it also works well for adding a single view or user flow to existing native applications. With a few steps, you can add new React Native based features, screens, views, etc.

The keys to integrating React Native components into your Android application are to:

> 1.Understand what React Native components you want to integrate.
>
> 2.Install react-native in your Android application root directory to create node_modules/ directory.
>
> 3.Create your actual React Native components in JavaScript.
>
> 4.Add com.facebook.react:react-native:+ and a maven pointing to the react-native binaries in node_modules/ to your build.gradle file.
>
> 5.Create a custom React Native specific Activity that creates a ReactRootView.
>
> 6.Start the React Native server and run your native application.
>
> 7.Optionally add more React Native components.
>
> 8.Debug.
>
> 9.Prepare for deployment.
>
> 10.Deploy and Profit!

More Detail refereed this link http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.42/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html#integration-with-existing-apps

Comment: sorry, i already checked that link. but no use.... in your answer 2nd point discussed about Root Directory...    
  F:\Ramaraju\workspace\MyOwnProject\app\src\main\java     this is my project path(Existing android project not React Project), please tell me what is the root directory there?

Comment: F:\Ramaraju\workspace\MyOwnProject\ this your root directory

Comment: okay please be patience, i'll explain my steps. please let me know what wrong i did............ 1>open cmd cd to root directory... 2>npm install -g react-native-cli with the second step it won't create any node_module folder in my root project

Comment: then you i'll type in cmd "npm init <yourProjectName>"

Comment: ok, package.json was created done upto this from "http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.42/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html#integration-with-existing-apps" reference. now prob with "index.android.js" file, i didn't find it in my root project. we have to create manually or it'll generate automatically?

Comment: could you share screen dumb

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145938/discussion-between-arunkumar-and-ramaraju).

Comment: send image in my mail arunkumarrmrj@gmail.com

Comment: sent to your mail, check and reply bro